# How to add an extra loop in this existing loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I have the following fiddle (click the 1 to see the board): http://jsfiddle.net/mauricederegt/vNpYe/1/

It creates a series of divs from the `var levels = [` part near the bottom of the script. The following part of the script loops through this to build up the board:

```
for (var i = 0, lngi = levels[level].length; i < lngi; i++) {
                for (var j = 0, lngj = levels[level][i].length; j < lngj; j++) {
                    if (levels[level][i][j] > 0) {
                    etc etc....
```

This all works great. The problem is, that I want to add another layer of blocks. In the current script I have commented out the part called `//layer2`. When layer1 is done, I want to loop it again to add layer 2 on top of layer 1, (and more layers later) so it will look like this:
[image]

Ofcourse some code extending needs to be done. For instance a `z-index` needs to be added and the loop needs to be re-written a bit.

I am not that great at coding, but I did some attempts to get this right. See this fiddle with my attempt. I have marked the lines with: `//NEW added: etc` where I have added stuff to make this work:
http://jsfiddle.net/mauricederegt/PCmws/1/

The fiddle doesn't work cause the coding isn't quite right yet. Hope someone can help me out here. What am I missing/doing wrong?

Kind regards

Comment: Please don't put tags in the title.

Comment: sounds like you need to turn this into a recursive function that takes in a set of data at a given level and adds it, then checks to see if there are any children levels and if so, calls itself with the next level's data.

Comment: I understand but my attempts failed doing so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break down where you are currently and what you would like to achieve:

- You currently have a loop that goes through every row and adds tiles
  to this row.
- You currently have a loop that goes through every layer and adds rows
  to this layer.
- What you need now is a loop that goes through every level and adds
  layers to this level.

---

Before I go further, I ask that you use more verbose names for your variables. 
While `i`, `j` and `lngi` might make sense in context, in my opinion it is much better to sacrifice conciseness with verbosity.
*Well, during development and prototyping at least.*

If you use things like `currentLevel` and `currentRow` for example, it makes things like `currentTileType = currentRow[currentColumnIndex]` sooo much more simple/straightforward :)

Of course there are always balances to be made and this is purely personal preference/opinion, but maybe with this example I can bring you over to the dark side.. ;)

---

Soo.. let's get stuck in...
The main change you'll see are the following additions..

Logically, it the same way that the one of the loops says "for every column in this row, I want to do this", it is actually just wrapping the existing loops saying "for every layer that I have defined, I want to do this (draw these rows)..."

---

```
       var currentGame = levels;

        console.info("currentGame = ", levels);

        // //Loop through levels in game
        // for (var currentLevelIndex = 0, numLevelsInGame = currentGame.length; currentLevelIndex < numLevelsInGame; currentLevelIndex++) {
            // var currentLevel = currentGame[currentLevelIndex];

            var currentLevel = currentGame[levelIndex];

            //Loop through layers in level
            for (var currentLayerIndex = 0, numLayersInLevel = currentLevel.length; currentLayerIndex < numLayersInLevel; currentLayerIndex++) {
                var currentLayer = currentLevel[currentLayerIndex];

                //Loop through rows in layer
                for (var currentRowIndex = 0, numRowsInLayer = currentLayer.length; currentRowIndex < numRowsInLayer; currentRowIndex++) {
                    var currentRow = currentLayer[currentRowIndex];

                    //Loop through columns in row
                    for (var currentColIndex = 0, numColsInRow = currentRow.length; currentColIndex < numColsInRow; currentColIndex++) {
                        var currentTileType = currentRow[currentColIndex];

                        //Do stuff based on what you have specified the current tile type as.. eg create it!!
```

See this fiddle for an updated version: 
http://jsfiddle.net/vNpYe/4/

Once you understand what is happening here, it is trivial to set the z-index of the layer to the "currentLayerIndex" (or some derivative thereof)

Comment: Note that each "row" resets the horizontal position to 0 and moves the "current position" down the page to the start of the new row.. Starting a new row is almost identical, but instead of moving all the way to the left and moving down, both axis are being reset to 0.

Comment: Thank you kwah for this clear explanation, it's very helpful. The tip for "logical naming" is a good point too. Especially when asking for help. I am going to study the fiddle some more. Thanks again for your time, learned something today!

Comment: I tend to think of things like this in "dimensions".. Eg, a tile is 0D (it is effectively a "point"), a row is 1D, a grid is 2D, the layering that you ask for is bringing it into 3D.. Beyond this it gets tricky to visualise (maybe 4D is the different levels in this example..?) but the point I am trying to make is that there is a function to create each "point" and for every dimension there is a loop.

Comment: So I've put in `z-index="' + currentLayer + '"` in the `this.getHTML = function () {` function, but i get `Undefined` as a value. Am I missing something at the `var tile = function`? Hmm it's 2:00 am, maybe I need a brake....